# How can I get a hotkey with ":" (colon) that works in AutoHotKey?

Tags: mapping, hotkeys, autohotkey, keymapping

I am trying the following but only the first part works:

```
*^!;::
Send <
return

*^!`:::
Send >
return
```

Apparently it is not the proper way to escape the colon ":". Do you have any idea on how to do this?

Comment: Short info for people find this. You escape (catch) the colon with an apostroph in AHK `\`:` not with `;:`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Erwin,

Try this:

```
+*^!;::
Send >
return
```

I assume here that the : character is actually shift ; on your keyboard.

By using the + and ; it should work.

Comment: Actually I would like {RIGHT ALT} + the ":" key (on a French keyboard layout) to produce >. The above code works with ; to produce <, but for some reason it does not work with :.

Comment: Erwin, I can't test this on my keyboard. Have you tried using ScanCodes e.g. RAlt & SC027:: (for the ; character on my kb) works.

Comment: I know, but I can't find the SC for the column. This is something you need to do on your PC with the AutoHotKey ScanCode application. When I do this, it will show the scan code for Shift and an other scancode for the semicolumn. To get the ScanCodes, right-click on the AHK icon, then [Open], then [Ctrl]+k, then press :, then [F5] to see the ScanCode in column 2. Salut.

Comment: P.s. the ScanCode for : on a French keyboard might be SC034, but I am not sure.